# How do you adjust offest and kernel stack size from an exploit?

Tags: buffer-overflow, kernel

Needless to I say I have no idea how to do this.

I'm performing a pentest and I found an exploit related the box : https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/44298

In the exploit comments, the author said :

> if different kernel adjust CRED offset + check kernel stack size

I see there is a variable for CRED : `#define CRED_OFFSET 0x5f8` but I have no idea how to adjust it. Also, I don't see anywhere in the exploit code where I should adjust the kernel stack size.

My Kernel is 4.4.0-81-generic (Unbutu 16)

How does this get solved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CRED_OFFSET` needs to be adjusted, so it's offset of `cred` member of `struct task_struct`. This can differ across kernel versions and compilation options that influence presence and size of other task_struct members.
Not sure what the quickest way to check this is. I'd get target kernel vmlinux and use `gdb` to get the offset.

Stack refers to `get_sp`, where it calculates stack pointer. This can again be different (I think on newer kernels stack can be independent of `task_struct`, so you can't just calculate it), but if kernel version is approximately the same, you'll probably get away leaving it as is.

Comment: omg. In conclusion I'm better of leaving Metasploit do this for me. lol. Anyway, how would you exactly use gdb to the offset ? Do you pass it a kernel image ?

Comment: Yes, you pass it a kernel image. You could cast 0 to pointer to task_struct, then print address of ->cred. From memory, something like `p &(((struct task_struct*)0)->cred)`

Comment: Wow. OK I think it's a bit out of my league. I'm pretty much a junior/intermediate pentester Thank you for your answer Domen